# How to bottom vertical align two divs with different font sizes in in a container div

Tags: html, css

I need the Invoice text to be left aligned and the Invoice # to be right aligned. I want them both to also be bottom aligned otherwise it looks odd with the an underline below. I have the following html:

```
<div style="height:75px; line-height:75px;">
    <div class="invoiceTitle">Invoice</div>
    <div class="invoiceNumber"># 12</div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.invoiceTitle
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 36px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.invoiceNumber
{
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I can't figure out how to get them both aligned vertically together. There's extra code in there to show things I've tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: When you use `vertical-align` you should add `display:table-cell`

Comment: @KobyDouek Can you please expand what you mean?

Comment: `vertical-align` doens't work on `display:inline`, which is the default. Try adding the `display:table-cell` attribute.

Comment: @Stephane can you please show any example link or image so we can clearly get the idea what you need.

Comment: @KobyDouek Didn't work

Comment: @msz I just want the invoiceTitle div to appear on the left and the InvoiceNumber div to appear on right at the same level vertically.

Comment: @KobyDouek - Your answer makes more sense. I believe you needed to also add width.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier, why would you make them `float`s if you want vertical align bottom? I mean what is your model?

Comment: Is it just to be `left` and `right` aligned?

Comment: @user10089632 It's just me trying different things to show my best attempt is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: bottom;` works only on inline blocks, whenever you used `float`s it moved to other [`Block formatting context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).
You can achieve that with `flexbox` & `align-items: flex-end`;

```css
.container {
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.invoiceTitle {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.invoiceNumber {
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invoiceTitle">Invoice</div>
  <div class="invoiceNumber"># 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are not both bottom aligned

Comment: They are aligned to the base line of each other.

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 1):

I've made it with relative/absolute positioning
I prefer using `inline-block` instead of `float`
Scroll down to see

```css
.container
{
    font-size: 36px;
    position:relative;
}
.invoiceTitle, .invoiceNumber{
   display:inline-block;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
}
.invoiceNumber{
 right:0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container" style="height:750px; line-height:75px;">
        <div class="invoiceTitle">Invoice</div>
        <div class="invoiceNumber"># 12</div>
    </div
```